# What's the maximum number of points at distance r or more inside a d-dimensional sphere of radius r?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, spheres, discrete-geometry, packing-problem

We have a sphere of radius $r$ in a $d$-dimensional space. What is the maximum amount of points that I can fit inside the sphere such as the distance between any pair of points is at least $r$? And strictly bigger than $r$?

I believe this is equivalent to packing d-dimensional spheres of radius r/2 inside a sphere of radius r.

If you have an idea on the order of the answer I would also appreciate it.

Thanks!

Related questions:

- [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803918/max-number-of-points-that-fit-in-on-a-sphere-of-radius-r-with-minimum-inter-poi) says that the number is 12 for d=3, what about for a general d?
- As opposed to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91420/maximum-number-of-points-with-a-fixed-minimum-distance-in-a-d-dimensional-ball), I'm only concerned for points at distance $r$, not any arbitrary distance.

Comment: [SPLAG](https://books.google.fi/books/about/Sphere_Packings_Lattices_and_Groups.html?id=upYwZ6cQumoC&redir_esc=y) has, among other goodies, extensive tables of what is known about kissing numbers in various dimensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, I believe you are seeking the [kissing number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kissing_number_problem).
In $d=2$, $6$ circles can touch a central $7$th, so
$7$ points at pairwise distance
$\ge r$ can be packed:

---

[image: Kissing2D]

---

In $d=3$, the kissing number is $12$, so you could surround
one sphere with $12$, leading to $13$ (not $12$ as you say) points
in the sphere each pair separated by at least $r$.

In dimension $d=4$, you would place the sphere centers at the vertices of the 
[$24$-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-cell),
and a $25$-th sphere in the center.

---

[image: 24-cell]

---

In $d=24$, you could pack $196560+1$ points.

Comment: +1 in $d=8$ we have a similar very nice packing coming from the $E_8$ (aka Gosset) lattice: 240 neighbors at distance $1$ from the origin (as well as other points).